# How to lock parent directory for a distant folder when creating connexion

Tags: ssh, winscp

I would like to share a folder from my computer Ubuntu 18.04 to others computers which are all on Windows.
That's why I installed ssh-serveur on mine, and WinSCP on the other one.

I create a connexion to my folder when the software is launched. It works because you arrived in my folder, and then you need a password each time you enter ...
Nevertheless when you are in the folder shared, you can enter to the parent directory and navigate into all my files, and I don't want !!

So, do you know how ocnfig a connexion to lock the parent directory of the folder chosen in the connexion ? Does it work from windows pc or mine (owner of the server ssh) ?

thanks you for your answear !

Comment: It's common in Linux not to duplicate the functionality of file permissions for SSH server. If a remote user authenticates as "you" then the premise is it's you. They can access remotely what you can access locally. Or did you create a separate user and they still can access all your files?

Comment: I didn't create a separate user. I just download ssh on Ubuntu, start the ssh-server and that all ... So you suggest to create another user from my Ubuntu computer, and authorize it to have access only on the shared folder ? thanks you